# AngularJS: Triggering stuff before ng-model executes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

On an AngularJS app, I have an HTML control that is binded to a js variable through an ng-model directive. For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVar" ng-change="aFunction()" />
```

I want to execute aFunction before myVar changes its value from ng-model, because I need to use the current value of myVar on aFunction.

I have been looking for ways to do or clarify about the execution order of directives on Angular, but haven't found a good answer yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a function before the model changes, use a directive to add a `$parser` to the `ngModelController`:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("preChange", function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
             ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                  scope.$eval(attrs.preChange, {$newValue: value});
                  return value;
             })
        }
    }
});
```

The above directive adds a `$parser` to the `ngModelController` which executes an AngularJS Expression defined by the `pre-change` attribute. The new value is exposed as `$newValue`.

Usage:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVar" pre-change="aFunction(myVar,$newValue)" />
```

From the Docs:

> ### `$parsers`
>
> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control reads value from the DOM. The functions are called in array order, each passing its return value through to the next. The last return value is forwarded to the $validators collection.

-- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference -- `$parsers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd8nL0yr/).

---

> Is `$newValue` a global variable (meaning it will store and replace its value on anything using pre-change)?`

The [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) defined by the `pre-change` [Expression Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) is evaluated using the directive's parent scope. The variable `$newValue` is **injected as a local name** as defined by an object that maps local names to values.

From the Docs:

> The 'isolate' scope object hash defines a set of local scope properties derived from attributes on the directive's element. These local properties are useful for aliasing values for templates. The keys in the object hash map to the name of the property on the isolate scope; the values define how the property is bound to the parent scope, via matching attributes on the directive's element:
>
> - `&` or `&attr` - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given `<my-component my-attr="count = count + value">` and the isolate scope definition scope: `{ localFn:'&myAttr' }`, the isolate scope property localFn will point to a function wrapper for the `count = count + value` expression. **Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope.** This can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is `increment($amount)` then we can specify the amount value by calling the localFn as `localFn({$amount: 22})`.

Or the expression could be `count = count + $amount`.

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API -- Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

As a convention, I prefer to prefix local names with `$` in order to distinguish them from ordinary scope variables.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to pass myVar parameter to aFunction? Is $newValue a global variable (meaning it will store and replace its value on anything using pre-change)?

Answer (score 1):

In the `$compile` documentation there's an explanation on directives execution order based on their priority. Just create a directive with a priority higher than `ng-model`s and then your directive's prelink function will be execute before `ng-model`s.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using ng-focus to execute a function that stores the value there on focus into another scope variable?

```
<body ng-app="focusApp">
  <div ng-controller="focusCtrl">
    <div>
        <input ng-focus='beforeChangeFunction(myVar)' type="text" ng-model="myVar" >
    </div>
    <div>
       original value: {{originalValue}}
    </div>
    <div>
       dynamic value: {{myVar}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

With a simple function like:

```
var app = angular.module('focusApp', []) 

  app.controller('focusCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.beforeChangeFunction = function(preEdit){
      $scope.originalValue = preEdit
    }

  })
```

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myku1sco/)

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot really depend on ng-focus for this, as I need a more reliable and scalable way to handle the before ng-model function happens in an input. For example, i need to apply this also to radio or select inputs, which doesn't fit so well into a focus based approach.

Comment: 100% understand.  Users could really screw up data with clicking around on the page or another window mid entry too.  If it was just for some feedback in the view ("your last guess was xyz") ala an improved placeholder-tip outside the box... it might not be so bad.